Related lists are not getting loaded in Dev Sandbox. Something went wrong We couldn't display your related list. Try again later
I am in a dev sandbox and even though my internet is good I am getting this error message for related lists and it keeps loading, What might be the possible reasons for this and how to debug it??


To display the Related List in Lightning, the Object's Field Level Security must be set to "Read" for all profiles within the Profile Setup.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383190&type=1

